# How can I use system anti-aliasing in Fireworks CS5?

Tags: fonts, adobe-fireworks, cs5, anti-aliasing

Fireworks used to have System Anti-Alias in the options, why is it not there anymore?
Does anyone have a solution for it?

I found these interesting links but no solution

- [The Ails Of Typographic Anti-Aliasing](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/02/the-ails-of-typographic-anti-aliasing/)
- [How Adobe ruined Fireworks CS4/CS5](http://blog.hipchat.com/2010/11/03/how-adobe-ruined-fireworks-cs4cs5/)

And the only one with a partial solution (but not working fine for me)

- [Simulate ClearType Text in Adobe Fireworks](http://www.idux.com/2009/11/26/simulate-cleartype-text-in-adobe-fireworks-cs4/)

Answer (score 2):

As a heavy user of all latest Fireworks versions I couldn't find this feature up to current CS6 version. I think it has something to do with the fact that ClearType is a [patented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType#Patents) Microsoft technology.

In addition to your links, [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/276135) on Adobe forum has some tips how to simulate system anti-aliasing in Fireworks. You can tune Fireworks styles to match system anti-aliasing by hand, but you can not make it look exactly the same, because:

1) ClearType is more than only anti-aliasing. ClearType has a sub-pixel rendering feature that makes vector lines of the font look more aligned to the pixel grid. Fireworks doesn't do this.

[image]

2) The sub-pixel rendering also differs per rendering engine that is used, for example: GDI and DirectWrite on Windows

[image]

Both use ClearType in the above image.

3) The anti-aliasing properties of ClearType are dynamic (configurable) and vary from system to system. You can change how ClearType looks within your Windows OS.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is super complete to understand better the problem,
And I don't want to reproduce exactly the System ClearType, I know it depends on the system you are using, but Fireworks is a complete solution for designing Web/Mobile applications, there should be a plug-in or a better workaround to achieve it